# Embedding a readonly SQLite Database in a DLL and conenct via Entity Framework

Tags: sqlite, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a requirement that my DLL should have a readonly database. I made my database as a embedded resource but i am not able to figure it out to connect to the database via entity framework.

```
try
        {
            var dataSet = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data") as System.Data.DataSet;
            dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add("SQLite Data Provider"
            , ".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
            , "System.Data.SQLite"
            , "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite");
        }
        catch (System.Data.ConstraintException) { }


        string providerName = "System.Data.SQLite";
        string serverName = "NameSpace.DB.sqlite";

        // Initialize the connection string builder for the
        // underlying provider.
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        // Set the properties for the data source.
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "DB.sqlite";
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
        string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
        new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        //Set the provider name.
        entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

        // Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/DataModel.DB.csdl|
                                res://*/DataModel.DB.ssdl|
                                res://*/DataModel.DB.msl";
        Console.WriteLine(entityBuilder.ToString());

        using (EntityConnection conn =
        new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.");

            _container = new MyEntities(conn);

            var usersList = _container.UserTable.ToList();
        }
```

It works only when we are copying the database to the client application. I don't want to provide the database as a separate file. I want to embedded it in the dll and give only the dll to other applications.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CL. said SQLite has to be in an independent .sqlite file, It cannot be embedded. Take a look at [SQL Server Compact](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417(v=sql.110).aspx). It is all you need, an embedded SQL Database that you can access using Entity Framework.

Here's a [tutorial](http://kosmisch.net/Blog/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/Archive/2014/10/12/d3fa749b20db46b68adb73acee7f2aaf.html) in how to connect to EF.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite databases are based on files.

The SQLite library has the ability to access files through a [virtual file system](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html), which would allow redirecting file accessing to somewhere else. So it would be possible to implement a VFS that accesses a resource.

However, System.Data.SQLite does not appear to allow registering your own VFS.

Comment: Running application which consumes this dll will have reference to SQLite supporting dlls. My only problem is to communicate to the embedded resource DB.Sqlite via entity framework